# Wordpress - theme doesn't show newest posts

Tags: wordpress, templates

I have a website with Wordpress and free template Creative on this link: http://kristinauhrinova.com.cluster3s23.dnsserver.eu/

I don't know why, but on bottom of the home page it doesn't show previews of newest added posts like in template demo http://dessign.net/unittheme/

Can you help?
Thanks, Filip.

Comment: you use custome post type in your site.???

Comment: check your index.php,  "Exit" keyword is exisit in you page

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is no loop in the index.php. You may have to write one yourself. To pull the previews if one doesn't already exist. Here's the WP Codex page about [The Loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

try to add this code on the home page,

```
<?php the_title(); ?><br />
<?php the_content(); ?>
```